# Checking if checkboxes are checked in an IF statement

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

How do I check if textboxes are checked in an IF statement? In my example I'm checking to see if "No" and "ely" have been selected along with either checkbox 3 or 4 been ticked then checkbox 2 needs to be automatically checked.

JavaScript code:

```
if(likeShield.value == "noShield" && chooseShield.value == "ely" &&  
            (document.getElementById("cb3").checked == true ||
             document.getElementById("cb4").checked == true))
{
    document.getElementById("cb2").checked=true;
}
```

The above code does not work. How can I fix this?

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myJavascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select id="likeShield" onchange="showTicks()">
   <option value="select1">Select</option>
   <option value="yesShield">Yes</option>
   <option value="noShield">No</option>
</select>

<select id="chooseShield" onchange="showTicks()">
   <option value="select1">Select</option>
   <option value="arc">Arcane</option>
   <option value="ely">Elysian</option>
<option value="spec">Spectral</option>
<option value="anylist">Choose any</option>
</select>

<table border = "1">
<tr>
   <th> tickbox </th>
   <th> shield parts </th>
   <th> description </th>
   <th> cost </th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb1"></td>
   <td> arc sigil </td>
   <td> Large magic part </td>
   <td> 5m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb2"></td>
   <td> arc shield </td>
   <td> A extremely powerful magic shield </td>
   <td> 60m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb3"></td>
   <td> arc special item </td>
   <td> special element </td>
   <td> 10m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb4"></td>
   <td> elysian sigil  </td>
   <td> A sigil found by dragons </td>
   <td> 50m </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb5"></td>
   <td> elysian shield </td>
   <td> A extremely powerful ranging shield </td>
   <td> 40m </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb6"></td>
   <td> elysian special item </td>
   <td> A special attack attached to shield </td>
   <td> 25m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb7"></td>
   <td> spectral sigil  </td>
   <td> easily obtainable from goblins </td>
   <td> 4m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb8"></td>
   <td> spectral shield </td>
   <td> Impressive stats </td>
   <td> 15m </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="cb9"></td>
   <td> spectral special item </td>
   <td> Does double damage </td>
   <td> 30m </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: include the relevant markup as well

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? Do you get an error? Is the condition always `false`?

Comment: did you prepare the variable likeShield ?

Comment: "Yo, dawg, I heard you like checkboxes so I put checkboxes in your checkboxes so you can check if your checkboxes are checked in an IF statement while you check..."

Comment: When I tick the checkbox 3 or 4, the checkbox 2 does not automatically check

Comment: did u checked my answer?

Comment: I made a rollback for clarity but OP clearly didn't want to pursue this question.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> document.getElementById("checkBox2").checked=true;
> ```

There's no such element in your code.

Perhaps you meant:

```
document.getElementById("cb2").checked=true;
```

Any further exploration of what you've done wrong would need a *testcase*, showing the full context in which you're executing your conditional statement. At present it's not at all clear whether it's in an event handler, or in a function call, or what...

Comment: This sort of thing is covered by basic debugging, really.

Comment: Woops sorry. Just changed it still doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: Haven't you heard? Crowdsoucing to StackOverflow is the new trend in basic debugging.

Comment: @user1832421: Please get used to saying more than "it doesn't work" if you want to report on the behaviour of a program. It's an utterly useless thing to say.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Oh, I've heard :( Lazy new generation

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to update the checkboxes when they're updated, you have to listen for the change event :

```
document.onload = function(){
var likeShield = document.getElementById("likeShield");
var chooseShield = document.getElementById("chooseShield");
var cb3 = document.getElementById("cb3");
var cb4 = document.getElementById("cb4");
function checkchecks() {
    if (
        likeShield.value=="noShield" && chooseShield.value == "ely"
        && (cb3.checked || cb4.checked)
    ) {
        document.getElementById("cb2").checked=true;
    }
}
likeShield.onchange=checkchecks;
chooseShield.onchange=checkchecks;
cb3.onchange=checkchecks;
cb4.onchange=checkchecks;
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/b55Zk/)

Comment: What is the element with ID `checkBox2`?

Comment: @user1832421 I added a demonstration in my answer.

Comment: Hi is the above meant to work I did try it but it did not work.

Comment: Did you check the link ? If you set the two select to their correct values and check the box 3 or 4, the box 2 is automatically selected. I supposed this was what you tried to do.

Comment: Yes it works on yours thanks. But where do I put the document.onload part in the js file?

Comment: You can put it just like in my answer, in your js file.

Comment: Ok since I already have a function would I need to add another function to the onchange in the html, or can i put this inside it. If so how would I. Already got a showTicks() function.

Comment: @dystroy Did you get my message?

Comment: You can add the content of my onload callback in yours. That's the simplest.

Comment: Ok. So it would be:

document.onload = function showTicks() {?